# external javascript and loaded file

Tags: jquery

```
<div id='panelB'>
<?php include ("inc/items.php");?>
</div>

<script src='../jquery-2.1.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='index.js'></script>
```

In this scenario everything works.
But later, inside `index.js` I have:

```
$("#modals_01 .linkL").click(function(){
$("#panelB").load("inc/items.php", { "category": a});
});
```

Now, javascript click.functions don't work on divs inside `items.php`.

I tried to place `<script>` tags inside `items.php` too, but in this case click functions (for example `slideToggle` a div) work twice !?

Comment: I don't know how many times this question has already been asked... Use `$('#panelB').on("click", "#modals_01 .linkL", function(){`

Comment: [Event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Comment: @Reagent As many times as closures inside loops sharing a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because jQuery is unaware of the items that are loaded in items.php. You have to use `on()` to delegate the events there, so those events will bubble up the DOM tree.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

For instance -

```
$(document).on('click', 'element', function() {
```

Now, when element is clicked the click event bubbles up to document where it will be acted on. The element that the event bubbles up to must exist at the time your jQuery code originally runs so jQuery is 'aware' of the element and can intercept bubbled events to that element. That makes document a fairly safe bet, but you can narrow it down if you desire.

Comment: Jay, I tried `$(document).on("click", "#modals_01 .linkL", function()...`, but still doesn't work. For example `$(".cardBtn").click(function()...` doesn't work. `cardBtn` is inside `items.php`

Comment: Then you should say `$(document).on('click', '.cardBtn', function()...`